# RCVMORE in zeromq

Tags: ruby, zeromq

I have been trying to determine if my socket has multipart message using [RCVMORE](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv)

> An application wishing to determine if a message is composed of
>   multiple parts does so by retrieving the value of the ZMQ_RCVMORE
>   socket option on the socket it is receiving the message from. If there
>   are no message parts to follow, or if the message is not composed of
>   multiple parts, ZMQ_RCVMORE shall report a value of zero. Otherwise,
>   ZMQ_RCVMORE shall report a value of 1, indicating that more message
>   parts are to follow.

extracted from [here](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv)

But, for some odd reason I keep getting the o/p as **0** even though the socket has message it can receive.

```
 socket.getsockopt(ZMQ::RCVMORE,[]).zero?
=> true ## the o/p is zero but the socket has msg to receive
 socket.recv_string(msg='')
 msg
=> "LA_1438789736_0840188"

socket.getsockopt(ZMQ::RCVMORE,[]).zero?
=> true ## again the o/p is zero but the socket still has msg it can receive

 socket.recv_string(msg='')
 msg
=> "PQ_188212111_0840188"

 socket.getsockopt(ZMQ::RCVMORE,[]).zero?
=> true ## again the same

 socket.recv_string(msg='')
 msg
=> "{\"seq\":1,\"call\":{},\"eval\":{},\"type\":\"connect\",\"vars\":{}}"
```

Not sure, what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE** : - The Zeromq ruby library(ruby client) currently in picture is [ffi-rzmq](https://github.com/chuckremes/ffi-rzmq)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the recvmsgs socket method? It does exactly what you need. Similarly you should call sendmsgs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/chuckremes/ffi-rzmq/ZMQ/Socket#recvmsgs-instance_method

Note that the correct flow of calls to zeromq is to FIRST call zmq_recv, THEN call zmq_getsockopt followed by zmq_recv, until the returned value is 0.

recv_string calls zmq_msg_close after reading the message contents, which frees all resources associated with the message. Your results may indicate you are not correctly sending multipart messages either.